# Placing two ul sections on the same horizontal line

Tags: css, html, positioning

I have a `nav` section with pull-down menu items (typical UL/LI using Bootstrap CSS) on the left side of the page.

I want to place another UL/LI on the right side of the page for Login and Register items. I would like the Login and Register items to be on the same horizontal line as the top of the pull-down menu line.

How can this be done?

Here is a jsFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/BaR3q/24/

Comment: Show us your code and what you've tried

Comment: The code is long. But what I did is just below the Nav section (where the pull-down menu is placed) I put the following
    <div class="float-right">
      and then UL with Login and Register Items.

Comment: @Zeaklous sorry I don't know how to place a code into the comment.

Comment: The only thing we can provide with the current lack-of-code is a really really generic example of how to do so

Comment: This is the link to jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/BaR3q/24/

Comment: [**Do you mean like this?**](http://jsfiddle.net/BaR3q/31/)

Comment: @Zeaklous  Yes. but it does not show my code when I run it. So you probably don't see the right code either.  Sorry.  I need to figure out how to correctly save the link so that I can share.

Comment: I believe this link should work:
http://jsfiddle.net/BaR3q/32/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take the second fiddle you posted and apply the basics of [my edit of your first fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BaR3q/31/) like so: [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/BaR3q/33/)

```
.nav-pills, .right-list  {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
.right-list ul li {
    float:left; /* Needs a float for some reason, not sure why */
}
```

Notice I changed the HTML a little by adding a `div` around the right list and moving it within the `nav`, which is where it should be

Alternatively, you could use `display:flex`. [**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/BaR3q/34/)

```
nav  {
    display:flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
}
.list-right {
    margin-top:10px;
}
```

Comment: @Hidalgo Anything else you need?

Comment: I appreciate your help.  I have read a bunch of on-line articles on display:inline-block and see how you came to the solution.  I also added an empty <div> styled to a cerain width and now the Login appears much further to the right (as I wanted). I still don't understand why verticle-aligh:middle works but :top doesn't.  But it is ok. It works.